# App does not perform a simple calculation

Tags: ios, swift

[Xcode screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Gzdj.png)

I have a simple app called BillSplitter that calculates a bill to display: input text fields for number of diners, bill total, and tip... 
when I run the app the grandTotal output does not calculate properly... the total and the tip do not calculate.

My app has 3 UITextfields Number of diners, Total cost of meal, and the tip. When I run the app and input data in the 3 fields and calculate My grand total is in correct. For example if I input. 2 diners, dinner cost $60, tip 10%. The result is as follows: The number of diners :2, Amount of Tip $6.00, Amount of bill: $60.00, Grand Total $70, each diner pays $30. What I should get is $66 for Grand Total and Each diner pays $33.

My Code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var dinersTextField: UITextField!  // number of diners
    @IBOutlet weak var totalCostTextField: UITextField! // bill total before
    @IBOutlet weak var resultTextLabel: UILabel!  // displays output of calculation
    @IBOutlet weak var tipTextField: UITextField!  // the tip

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func calculate(_ sender: Any) {
        if let dinerStr = dinersTextField.text, let tipStr = tipTextField.text, let totalStr =   totalCostTextField.text, let diner = Double(dinerStr), let tip = Double(tipStr), let total =  Double(totalStr) {
            let formattedDiners = String(format: "%.0f", diner)
            let formattedCost = String(format: "%.2f", total)
            let formattedTip = String(format: "%.2f", (total * tip) / 100)
            let formattedGTotal = String(format: "%.2f", (total + tip))
            let formattedDinerPays = String(format: "%.2f", (total / diner))

            resultTextLabel.text = "The number of diners: \(formattedDiners)\nAmount of Tip: $\(formattedTip)\nAmount of bill: $\(formattedCost)\nGrand Total: $\(formattedGTotal)\nEach diner pays: $\(formattedDinerPays)"
        }
    }
    /// hide keyboard
    @IBAction func dismissKeyboard(_ sender: Any) {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your code in the question and not a picture of the code.

Comment: Closing as unclear

Comment: What do yo mean does not calculate? For your question to be considered on-topic, include the expected and the actual behaviour in your question. Some example inputs/outputs would also help.

Comment: Add breakpoint and debug to check assumed values

Comment: My app has 3 UITextfields  Number of  diners, Total cost of meal, and the tip.  When I run the app and input data in the 3 fields and calculate My grand total is in correct.  For example if I input.  2 diners, dinner cost $60, tip 10%. The result is  as follows:   The number of diners :2, Amount of Tip $6.00, Amount of bill: $60.00, Grand Total $70, each diner pays $30.  What I should get is $66 for Grand Total and Each diner pays $33.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem with your maths. You are adding the tip percentage to the total not the tip value and you are dividing the cost by the diners not the cost + tip .

```
let formattedGTotal = String(format: "%.2f", (total + tip))
let formattedDinerPays = String(format: "%.2f", (total / diner))
```

With your example this means that you have a total of $60 and a tip of 10% and the calculation you are doing is 60 + 10 giving you the 70. Then to calculate what the diner pays you are doing 60 / 2 giving you the 30.

You should change these two lines to the following:

```
let formattedGTotal = String(format: "%.2f", total + ((total * tip) / 100))
let formattedDinerPays = String(format: "%.2f", ((total + ((total * tip) / 100)) / diner))
```

You could calculate the total with the tip first and reuse it to be more efficient:

```
let totalWithTip = total + ((total * tip) / 100)
```

Then you could use totalWithTip to calculate what the diner pays using

```
let formattedDinerPays = String(format: "%.2f", (totalWithTip / diner))
```